# While/Do/Done Loop Error In Bash Script In Crontab

Tags: linux, bash, unix, cron

I'm trying to run a abash script through crontab and every time I try to, the script never runs and I get an error that reads: "[[: Not Found"

I'm currently using a while loop with the following coding:

```
SHELL/=bin/sh

padtowidth=2
START=0
END=15
i=${START}

while [[ ${i} -le ${END} ]]
do

done
((i = i + 1))
```

I'm not sure why crontab doesn't like the double brackets in the beginning...

Comment: cron isn't the problem.  `[[` is invalid syntax in sh.  It is a bashism.

Comment: Setting the value of `SHELL` in a script is not recommended. (It's unlikely it does what you think it does.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `[[...]]` is BASH specific.

Change your shell to BASH using:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

Even arithmetic evaluation brackets `((...))` are not supported in `sh` (used as last line in your script)

Answer (score 3):

Run your script in crontab explicitly with `bash` as `/bin/sh` is the default shell that crontab uses e.g.

```
* ... * /bin/bash /path/to/your/script.sh
```

And I'm not sure what `SHELL/=bin/sh` does but it is a malformed assignment. At least it should be `SHELL=/bin/sh`.